# width and height of imageview in dynamic layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I'm using dynamic layout I want to set width and height of a `ImageView`. The code is below. How can I set the height and width of an `ImageView` in a given layout? Any help is highly appreciated.

```
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
    TextView text1 = new TextView(mContext);
    text1.setText(Constants.vctrCategory.elementAt(counter).toString());
    LayoutParams params1 = new    LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    text1.setLayoutParams(params1);
    text1.setTextSize(20);
    layout.addView(text1);
    ImageView image = new ImageView(mContext);
    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    layout.addView(image);
    counter++;
    return layout;
```

Comment: I don't understand... You just set LayoutParams on the TextView, why can't you do the same on the ImageView?

Comment: I set the imageview but it doesn't display .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather can calling calling `addView()` with just the `ImageView`, you could use the version that also takes two integers for the width and height:

[addView(View child, int width, int height)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int,%20int%29)

Alternatively, you can set the width and/or height directly on the view's `LayoutParams`, i.e. after the `layout.addView(image)` call in your own snippet:

```
layout.addView(image);
layout.getLayoutParams().width = width;
layout.getLayoutParams().height = height;
```

Basically it's similar to what you're already doing for the `TextView`.

Comment: I tried the above code but image in not display only text is display:(

Comment: @rameesha: did you step through your code at runtime with a debugger attached to confirm that you're actually setting a valid `bitmap` value on the `ImageView`?

Answer (score 0):

> I set the imageview but it doesn't display

Try something like this:

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

LayoutParams params1 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
TextView text1 = new TextView(this);
text1.setText(Constants.vctrCategory.elementAt(counter).toString());
text1.setTextSize(20);
layout.addView(text1, params1);

LayoutParams params2 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
layout.addView(image, params2);

count++;
return layout;
```

There are a lot of other LayoutParams classes, make sure that you import RelativeLayout.LayoutParams. And if this still "doesn't display" then `bitmap` is the likely culprit.

Comment: I tried the above code but image in not display only text is display:(

Comment: Then the bitmap is the problem. Use your debugger to track the value of `bitmap`.